# Computer turns on then turns off after a second

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard

Some time ago I "broke" the BIOS of my ASUS P8P67 MoBo (with a wrong forced BIOS update, PC specs below).
I replaced that "Corrupted BIOS" with ASUS P8P67 DELUXE "Working BIOS".
Edit: I forced the BIOS update (but with the right image) after turning it on, it remains on for a millisecond, then the same thing for the second time, and for the third time, it remains on forever, and nothing on the screen.

How can I recover the BIOS?

PC specs:

> ASUS P8P67 (with P8P67 DELUXE BIOS)
> i5-2500K (I'll replace it with i7-3770)
> XILENCE Performance C series CPU FAN
> Sapphire Radeon HD 5770
> Mars Gaming MP650II PSU

Comment: I don't think that you have many other options than to clear the CMOS.  Why are you worried about doing this?

Comment: I tried cleaning the cmos, but the problem persists

Comment: If you cleared the CMOS AFTER installing the correct BIOS and it still will not boot.. my guess is that you either STILL do not have the correct firmware installed OR you have created some sort of hardware error in the mean time.

Comment: I cleaned the CMOS before flashing correct BIOS (when there was the P8P67 DELUXE bios)

Comment: If you know a solution then write an answer. Or better edit your not-an-answer below and make it a proper answer before it gets deleted.

Comment: it's not a solution, i solved the problem.

Comment: You've found a solution that solved your problem. Please put that in your answer. I've rolled back your edit. We're not a forum, we don't do `(SOLVED)` edits here - questions are for asking questions (not answering them), answers are for answering questions (not posting updates), if you know an answer to a question (including yours) you post it as an answer, if someone (including you) posts an answer that solves your problem you mark it as accepted rather than add `(SOLVED)`.

Comment: I placed your solution in your answer. You can still edit both the question and the answer, but please do not rollback to their previous states. The question should state the problem; it does now. The answer should provide a solution; it does now. This is how the things should be.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm newto SuperUser,i've registered last week

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I recovered the BIOS With the CH314A USB Programmer.